# A character to numeric conversion process failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, informix, parameterized-query

I face the following exception when i try to use parametrized query with `informix` .

```
A character to numeric conversion process failed
```

---

```
                    StringBuilder sQuery = new StringBuilder();
                    Dictionary<string, string> paramList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    cmdTxt.Append(" UPDATE userwidgetto SET widget_color = ?, widget_column = ?, widget_order = ?,widget_state = ?,widget_type = ? ");
                    cmdTxt.Append(" WHERE process_id = ? AND emp_num = ? ");

                    paramList.Add("process_id", Process_id.ToString());
                    paramList.Add("emp_num", Emp_num.ToString());
                    paramList.Add("widget_color", Widget_color.TrimEnd());
                    paramList.Add("widget_column", Widget_column.ToString().TrimEnd());
                    paramList.Add("widget_order", Widget_order.ToString());
                    paramList.Add("widget_state", Widget_state.ToString());
                    paramList.Add("widget_type", Widget_type.ToString());
                    affectedRow = DAL_Helper.Execute_NonQuery(cmdTxt.ToString(), CommandType.Text, paramList);
```

---

```
public int Execute_NonQuery(string cmdText, CommandType cmdType, Dictionary<string, string> Param_arr)
            {
                Open_Connection();
                int return_val = -1;
                command.CommandText = cmdText;
                command.CommandType = cmdType;
                command.Transaction = current_trans;
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                if (Param_arr != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parameter in Param_arr)
                    {
                        param = command.CreateParameter();
                        param.ParameterName = parameter.Key.ToString();
                        if (parameter.Value.ToString() == "Null" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Value))
                            param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            param.Value = parameter.Value.ToString();
                        command.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    return_val = command.ExecuteNonQuery();//means no error message //OK                
                }
                catch (IfxException ifxEx)// Handle IBM.data.informix : mostly catched
                {
                    return_val = ifxEx.Errors[0].NativeError;
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    ErrMapping.WriteLog("\r\n" + Ex.Message);
                    return_val = ExCodeConst;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Close_Connection();
                }
                return return_val;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using an OleDb client. 
In that case, the parameters should be inserted in the same exact position order of you command string placeholders (`?`)

```
cmdTxt.Append(" UPDATE userwidgetto SET widget_color = ?, widget_column = ?, widget_order = ?,widget_state = ?,widget_type = ? ");
cmdTxt.Append(" WHERE process_id = ? AND emp_num = ? ");
paramList.Add("widget_color", Widget_color.TrimEnd());
paramList.Add("widget_column", Widget_column.ToString().TrimEnd());
paramList.Add("widget_order", Widget_order.ToString());
paramList.Add("widget_state", Widget_state.ToString());
paramList.Add("widget_type", Widget_type.ToString()); 
paramList.Add("process_id", Process_id.ToString());
paramList.Add("emp_num", Emp_num.ToString());
affectedRow = DAL_Helper.Execute_NonQuery(cmdTxt.ToString(), CommandType.Text, paramList);
```

Also the Dictionary<string, string> paramList forces every value passed to the DAL_Helper to be of string type.
And, I think, this  is not the case from the parameters names given (**process_id** is not a string in the database table right?).
As someone as already suggested in a comment, you should change the paramList to be a Dictionary<string, object> and then add the parameters with a string conversion only where is appropriate (meaning, the datatype of the table column is a string type).

Comment: Great this solve my problem ..really thanks , but i don't understand the last comment i already have a dictionary how to allow to accept all datatypes without the need to convert `tostring()`

Comment: Could u give me a simple example please ?

Comment: If you declare `Dictionary<string, object> paramList` then you could write `paramList.Add("process_id", Process_id);`. Your DAL_Helper class, when add this parameter to the OleDbParameterCollection to update your table, will see that you have an object of integer type and will pass an integer to the command that update your table.

Comment: Will be very useful if you could also show the code of DAL_Helper.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Really weird, every parameter is converted to a string. I don't know Informix, and the OleDb driver used to work with the database backend, but I think you have big problems here. Do you have only string columns in your tables? (Just saying to clear things, it will be an enourmous error)

Comment: :) i have all types ,but we use this layer longtime ago , Could u provide suggestions to enhance this method ?